# Calling code after .each in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am uploading files to a server and want to switch some buttons out when all of the files are done uploading. The files are uploaded in a `.each` so the code should run after that. I have been researching this and see that `.each` is synchronous so it should work if I just put the code outside the `.each` but it's not working.

I am wondering if this is because within the `.each` there's an ajax call.

I've also seen examples of counting while you're looping and just calling the code on the last iteration but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Current basic code - not working

```
$.each( function () {
  ...
});
$("#btnNext").removeAttr("hidden") //want this to run after
```

I also tried a promise which errored in the console

```
$.each( function () {
  ...
}).promise().done(function() {
    $("#btnNext").removeAttr("hidden")
});
```

Comment: @Liam He's not trying to return anything, just wait for all of them to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if this is because within the .each there's an ajax call.

This is the reason. The AJAX calls are asynchronous, hence the `removeAttr()` call will happen long before those requests complete.

To solve this store the deferred objects returned form the AJAX calls in an array, then apply them to `$.when()`. In the callback of the you can execute whatever logic needs to run after all requests have completed.

```
var requests = [];
$.each( function () {
  requests.push($.ajax({
    // your ajax options here...
  }));
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
  $("#btnNext").removeAttr("hidden");
});
```